# Webstorm Import url issues with Angular 2

Tags: node.js, import, typescript, angular, webstorm

Looking for some guidance on WebStorm v11 and using Angular2 imports, I'm also on a Mac.

Whenever I am creating a component and I import for example `Http` service from Angular 2, WebStorm does its thing and automatically imports it on the page for me. However the URL for the import is a crazy string, but in all the demos I've seen it just imports to a simple string like this:

```
import {Http} from "angular2/core";
```

but mine will import like this:

```
import {Http} from "../../../node_modules/angular2/src/http/http";
```

So I will manually go and change it to the more simple one for readability and it still works fine. Any ideas or help on how I could get it to import with the simple string?

Comment: can it be that WebStorm doesn't know about ambient modules, it is known to have all sorts of issues? Have you tried another editor? :)

Comment: You should try WebStorm 2016.1 RC: https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/nextversion/
Tried with Http in TypeScript - adds import from "angular2/http", which is correct, I believe.

Comment: Sweet thx for the update on the next release I will update!